# one dynamic body with many circle shape type fixture reduces fps in libgdx box2d

Tags: libgdx, box2d

```
// alpts is an array list of vector2 type

bodyDef.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(0, 0);
Body body=world.createBody(bodyDef);
body.setUserData("chain");

for(int i=0;  i<alpts.size(); i++) {
      Vector2 vector=alpts.get(i);
      CircleShape shape=new CircleShape();
      shape.setRadius(.2f);
      shape.setPosition(vector);
      fixDef.shape=shape;
      fixDef.density=1;
      fixDef.friction=1f;
      fixDef.restitution=.5f;                 
     if(i>0) {
          Vector2 start=alpts.get(i-1);
          Vector2 end=alpts.get(i);                  
      }

      Fixture fixture=body.createFixture(fixDef);       

      String str="images/circle.png";
      MySprite sprite=new MySprite(makingTexture(str));
      sprite.setSize(.35f,.35f);
      sprite.setPosition(vector.x,vector.y);
      fixture.setUserData(sprite);                
      shape.dispose();
}
```

1. trying to make a dynamic body with many circle shape type fixtures on touch up.
2. After making two or three body it reduces the frame per seconds.

Comment: What is your question.

Comment: i am making one box2d dynamic body which is having more than one fixture.the shape type of fixture is circle shape on every touchUp. Each body is having 10 or more fixture.So my question is that after making more bodies the fps of my game is slow down

Comment: It's not box2d that is slowing it down, hopefully its your way of implementation. Show some code luke!

Comment: alpts is an ArrayList of vector2 type